# URL Parse, write + redirect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, url-rewriting, redirect

My URL is arranged in the following format.

**http(s)://www.example.com/partner/retailer.aspx**

*(which I think is protocol+authority+path+file
)*

I would like to parse, rewrite and then redirect this url **when a mobile device is used.**

For example:

**http(s)://www.example.com/partner/retailer.aspx**

would become

**http(s)://www.example.com/details.aspx?p=retailer**

So, /partner/ becomes /details.aspx  , and the file retailer.aspx is converted to a query string p=retailer.

Also, the protocol of the page (whether http or https) should be preserved through the redirect.

What would be the easiest javascript way of doing this?

Many thanks,
James.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + 
    window.location.hostname + '/' + 
    'details.aspx' + 
    '?p=' + window.location.pathname.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  How would I tie this into one of the fairly standard .js mob redirect scripts?

Comment: ...and how would I make it only apply the redirect if the /partner/retailer.aspx was present, i.e - to not apply the redirect, if only the protocol + hostname (http://www.example.com) are present.  Sorry to keep extending the question... :(

Comment: Your solution only works for me if I have http://www.example.com - in which case it becomes 'http://www.example.com/details.aspx?p=/'.  Nothing happens if I have http://www.example.com/partner/retailer.aspx